# Solr search query result are found when using qf parameter

Tags: java, search, solr

I have the following query, which in my opinion is incorrect because the parentheses are not closed properly and when I execute it there are no matches found as expected. But then when I add the qf parameter inside solr gui page with value: title, I get 1 result. Isn't qf parameter used only for boosting fields as pointed in documentation https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html and why I am getting results after using it?

```
((BookNumber:"BR\+9258")))
```

Here are my fields described in schema.xml

```
  <field name="BookNumber" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I use edismax query parser and solr gui hosted at localhost to execute queries. Below are images without and with qf parameter.
[image: Solr query without qf parameter]

[image: Solr query with qf parameter]

Comment: The `qf` field can be used for boosting but it's not its only use, it can also use to indicate multiple fields to search if the user did not specify a field. In you case it should not have an effect on the search since you search text is explicitly indicated the field to search (BookNumber) but I have no idea why it did.

Comment: It is interesting that the search without the `qf` value searched both `BookNumber` and `_text_` fields whereas the field where you indicated a `qf` value it only searched `BookNumber`